# select 17 milion records in sql server is very slow

Tags: sql-server, indexing, sql-execution-plan

I try to select a table with 17 Million Records .
It takes about 10 min .
Here you can see the Live execution plan .

[image]

Here is my table structure :

```
CREATE TABLE [bas].[GatewayReceipt](
    [Id] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CustomerId] [INT] NULL,
    [UserId] [INT] NOT NULL,
    [RefNumber] [NVARCHAR](200) NULL,
    [ResNumber] [NVARCHAR](200) NULL,
    [Price] [DECIMAL](18, 5) NOT NULL,
    [GatewayChannelId] [INT] NOT NULL,
    [StatusId] [INT] NOT NULL,
    [EntryDate] [DATETIME] NOT NULL,
    [ModifyDate] [DATETIME] NULL,
    [RowVersion] [TIMESTAMP] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Bas_GatewayReceipt] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [FG_ATS]
) ON [FG_ATS]
GO
```

[image]

As a note I have 3 non-clustered index on
1:CustomerId
2:customerIdAndUserId
3:gatewaychannelId

my query :

```
select * from  bas.GatewayReceipt where  gatewaychannelId in (1,2,3)
```

why my query is slow ?

Comment: And what is your question? SELECT * FROM without WHERE can not use indexes

Comment: @Sergey sorry i changed the query . i have a where clause on gatewaychannelid

Comment: @Sergey as a main question Why the select query without where should be so slow ?

Comment: Clearly, however, you don't have an covering index as the RDBMS is *scanning* the **entire** table.

Comment: @Larnu I don't have

Comment: I also suspect that gatewaychannelId is not used.May be because a majority of rows satisfy this condition and it is cheaper to scan the whole table

Comment: @Sergey yes the whole rows has a same channelid

Comment: You seriously all seem to ignore the thing. It doesn ot matter whether there is an index or not - even without index, 17 million row scan should NOT TAKE 10 minutes on modern hardware. Is hit running on a 5  year old phone, 20 year old computer?  VERY VERY VERY little RAM? 10 minutes is outrageous, index or not.

Comment: What exactly does "It takes about 10 min" mean? Do you measure from an application point-of-view? How slow is the application to retrieve the resultset and do something with it? And what does that application do with the resultset? How slow is the network connection between server and app? Even if the execution plan can be improved, you might not see much improvement if the problem lies within the consumption of the resultset.

Comment: Or showing it. Dumping 17 million rows on a dataset that is not virtualized can well take that time - and is a classical programming mistake, but it is absolutely not "the database server is slow".

Comment: Are you really trying to render the entire table (17 million rows) to Management Studio? Why?

Answer (score 5):

The results are slow primarily due to time the client application (SSMS) needs to render the large 17 million row result.

To wit, it takes SSMS about 70 seconds to display the 10 million row result of this query on my PC in a grid and task manager shows SSMS is completely CPU bound during execution:

```
WITH 
     t10 AS (SELECT n FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) t(n))
    ,t1k AS (SELECT 0 AS n FROM t10 AS a CROSS JOIN t10 AS b CROSS JOIN t10 AS c)
    ,t10m AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) AS num FROM t1k AS a CROSS JOIN t1k AS b CROSS JOIN t10 AS c)
SELECT num
FROM t10m;
```

Repeating the same query without the full rendering (Query-->Options-->Grid-->Discard results after execution), it takes only 12 seconds to retrieve the rows but not display them.

Consider end-to-end response time is a measure of both client and server time.

Answer (score -1):

The table needs an `INDEX` *starting with* `gatewaychannelId`.

However, if most or all the rows in the table are values 1, 2, or 3, the index would actually slow down the query.  In this case, it is faster to simply read the table, filtering out the few rows that do not apply.